# What is the definition of a Salesforce API call?

Tags: api

Want counts as a API call in salesforce?

Is it an outbound call or both inbound and outbound calls?

Also

With Salesforce Connect it is allowed to map Salesforce with external Objects.  Having available 1 license of Salesforce connect how many external objects can be mapped?

o   Only one a table (i.e table of Orders)

o   an Entity (i.e Orders and related information from various tables)

o   only one System (i.e ERP System).

Comment: Its for Inbound call, outbound calls are unlimited.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of limits, an API call is an inbound API call.